# Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0 when importing Firebase to a code sample

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I imported the sample app in Android Studio under the location section. I then proceeded to update most of the dependancies. I then attempted to add Firebase and that's when things went south. The module build.gradle is below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.0.1'
    compile project(':Shared')
    wearApp project(':Wearable')
}

// The sample build uses multiple directories to
// keep boilerplate and common code separate from
// the main sample code.
List<String> dirs = [
        'main',     // main sample code; look here for the interesting stuff.
        'common',   // components that are reused by multiple samples
        'template'] // boilerplate code that is generated by the sample template process

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            dirs.each { dir ->
                java.srcDirs "src/${dir}/java"
                res.srcDirs "src/${dir}/res"
            }
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']

    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The root build.gradle is below.

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

And the error I receive is :

Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
    file:/C:/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
Required by:
    :ToledoZoo:unspecified

Using the latest SDK, and all. Added the google.json file to the app directory as well. I am sure it is something small I am missing, but yet... still missing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The module build.gradle is below

`app/` is a module, and the `buildscript` block should not be within that.

> The app build.gradle is below.

If by this, you mean `build.gradle` in the **root** of the project, then it is that file where you add the `classpath` of the play services.

Refer. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

Note, when the documentation says

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

You do not literally copy the `// ...` pieces. It means "leave what is there already".

---

If you have a single module Gradle project, then that might make sense looking at your question, and so you need to have

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

// rest of gradle file
```

Comment: Yeah, I had gotten to the point that I was copying word for word to make sure I hadn't made a typo somewhere.... frustration had set in long ago. Your comment though made me think more about how it was setup and you are correct (if I am reading it right... if I am reading it wrong, you at least pointed me in the right direction.)  This is the first time I have seen the "non conventional" setup as opposed to the separated module/root setup. So I added the classpath where you mentioned and removed it totally from the other one and we happenly compile now! Thank you! More eyes always help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Gradle expert.  That said, the layout of your `build.gradle` files is unconventional.  Typically, in the module file, the `dependencies` block is after the `android` block.  Examples of build files are in the Firebase sample project.  Take a look at this [sample project build file](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/build.gradle) and this [sample module build file](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/build.gradle).

Comment: Extremely unconventional IMO too. But again it was an imported sample right from Android Studio so I figured I might as well play around with it to see what's what.